# Improvement on copy array elements numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a question regarding variable assignation and memory allocation in a simple case.

Imagine that I am initialising a state vector `x`, with initial value `x0`. I am then making iterative updates on that state vector with buffer array `X` and after each iteration, I store the new state vector in a storage list `L`. An outline of my initial implementation can be found in the following snippet:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(11)

x0 = 1
L = [x0]
x = x0

X = np.zeros((3,1))

for i in range(10):
    X[-1, :] = np.random.normal() # To simulate operations on X
    x = X[-1, :]
    L.append(x)

print(L)
```

Which would print that L holds

```
[1 array([-1.06560298]) array([-1.06560298]) array([-1.06560298])
 array([-1.06560298]) array([-1.06560298]) array([-1.06560298])
 array([-1.06560298]) array([-1.06560298]) array([-1.06560298])
 array([-1.06560298])]
```

Because when `x` is appended to L, only the reference to `X[-1, :]` is added, not the actual value.

The solution I could find is to use `np.copy` to copy the values of the last row of `X` into `x` and then append it, as can be seen in the following snippet.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(11)

x0 = 1
L = [x0]
x = x0

X = np.zeros((3,1))

for i in range(10):
    X[-1, :] = np.random.normal() # To simulate operations on X
    x = np.copy(X[-1, :])
    L.append(x)

print(L)
```

The output shows that indeed the modifications on the state `x` are correctly recorded.

```
[1 array([1.74945474]) array([-0.286073]) array([-0.48456513])
 array([-2.65331856]) array([-0.00828463]) array([-0.31963136])
 array([-0.53662936]) array([0.31540267]) array([0.42105072])
 array([-1.06560298])]
```

I wonder if there would be a more elegant or efficient way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of the `X` array?  Especially reusing it?

Comment: you can see `X` as a computational helper. In each iteration, its values are updated row by row (row i depending on rows 0, ..., i-1) and what we are interested in at the end of the iteration is the value of the last row

Comment: Accumulating a mutable variable in a list is a well known Python pitfall.  A list stores references, not values.  In a case like this you have ask yourself whether mutating `X` (`X[...]=....`) is worth it, if you still have to make a copy.  The array assignment in the accepted answer is also making a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix numpy arrays and python lists if you can avoid it. If you know the number of iterations, pre-allocate a buffer to hold the whole thing (e.g., with [`np.empty`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html)):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(11)

N = 10

L = np.empty(N)
L[0] = 1

X = np.zeros(3)

for i in range(N):
    L[i] = X[-1] = np.random.normal()

print(L)
```

On the other hand, if all you need is to get the scalar from a 1-element array, you can use the [`item`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method:

```
x = X[:, -1].item()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll award you the answer because it does work for this simple case, and because it gave me an idea, but in my actual problem I can't know in advance how many iterations I will need.

Comment: @pierresegonne. Do you have an upper bound?

Comment: I thought about it, having a array of the size of the upper bound and then clip it afterwards. But my use case is an ode solver (esdirk23 to be exact) with adaptive step size, so I can't find an easy upper bound (there is one for sure but I have to investigate)

Comment: @pierresegonne. Another way is to keep allocating blocks and placing them in a `deque` or a `list`. If you only need access to the last block, this shouldn't be a problem. You can combine blocks at the end. This will likely be faster than trying to append each element individually, although `list` does offer ammortized `O(n)` append time in the long run.

Comment: In most SO questions I've found that list append is competitive with assignment to a preallocated array.

Comment: @hpaulj. Agreed. It goes back to premature optimization being the root of all evil and all. the last snippet is probably the one OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you want to do, but maybe `numpy.append()` is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(11)

x = np.array([1.])

for i in range(10):
    x = np.append(x, np.random.normal())

print(x)
```

Comment: It's better to use a python list and convert to an array at the end than to reallocate the entire array at e every iteration.